# Why does multiprocessing floating-point submatrices cause unexpected output?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I wrote a program to train a bigram model. To speed it up, I decided to split the counts matrix, process the submatrices on multiple threads, then reconcatenate them into one probability matrix.

I have a version of the code without multi-processing which works correctly, and the multi-processing version which only works with `n_processes = 1`. If I try to run it with 2, 8 or 16 processes, the first submatrix is processed correctly (the probabilities sum up to 1 in each row), while all the others contain numbers which are all over the place (they do not get progressively worse going from 2 to 16, they're just numbers ranging between 0.001 and 250.0)

Function that gets applied to the submatrices:

```
def kn_probs(bigram_counts, type_counts, d=0.75):
"""
Calculate Kneser-Ney probabilities on a matrix of bigram counts.

:param bigram_counts: 2D matrix of integer counts of bigrams
:param type_counts: number of bigram types, list of row types
counts, list of col types counts.
:param d: discount value subtracted from the count of each bigram
:return: a 2D matrix containing the Kneser-Ney bigram probabilities
"""
n_bigram_types, row_types_counts, col_types_counts = type_counts

# initialise matrix
kn_probs = np.zeros((len(bigram_counts), len(bigram_counts[0])), dtype=np.float16)

# iterate through the matrix
for row_i, row in enumerate(bigram_counts):
    
    # compute the pre_word (i.e. row) terms
    pre_word_count = np.sum(row)
    n_pre_word_followers = row_types_counts[row_i]
    kn_lambda = (d / pre_word_count) * n_pre_word_followers
    
    # iterate through the row
    for col_i, bigram_count in enumerate(row):
        
        n_word_precedents = col_types_counts[col_i]
        
        # compute KN prob and save it
        kn_prob = (max(bigram_count-d, 0) / pre_word_count)\
                    + (kn_lambda * (n_word_precedents / n_bigram_types))
        kn_probs[row_i][col_i] = kn_prob

return kn_probs
```

Multiprocessing part:

```
# split bigram_counts to allow for multiprocessing
n_processes = 16
bigram_counts_chunks = np.array_split(bigram_counts, n_processes)
length = len(bigram_counts)
del(bigram_counts)

# create a pool of worker processes
with mp.Pool(n_processes) as p:
    
    # compute type counts separately and merge them (needed for Kneser-Ney smoothing)
    chunks_type_counts = p.map(count_types, bigram_counts_chunks)
    n_bigram_types = sum([type_counts[0] for type_counts in chunks_type_counts])
    row_types_counts = np.concatenate([type_counts[1] for type_counts in chunks_type_counts])
    col_types_counts = [0] * length
    for type_counts in chunks_type_counts:
        col_types_counts = np.add(col_types_counts, type_counts[2])
    type_counts = (n_bigram_types, row_types_counts, col_types_counts)
    
    # map the kn_probs() function to each chunk in parallel
    bigram_probs_chunks = p.starmap(kn_probs, zip(bigram_counts_chunks, itertools.repeat(type_counts)))
    del(bigram_counts_chunks)
    
# concatenate chunks into one array
bigram_probs = np.concatenate(bigram_probs_chunks)
```

Specifics: HP laptop with Windows 11, 64-bit, Python 3.11.0, 16GB RAM

Comment: Please do not put image but the code itself as a text.

Comment: What is `bigram_counts`'s shape? Is it splitting the way you expect? Have you tried any *experiments* with simpler calcs and smaller data with some logging so you can see what might be happening in each process?

Comment: @wwii It is a 2D matrix. On the data I have tested it it gets to roughly 1300x1300. It is splitting as I expected. I will try with even smaller data.